# How to check size of android application in android studio?

Tags: android, performance, android-studio

I want to connect the android application on my physical device and i get a message that I don't have enough memory on the phone.

How to check inside android studio size of my applications ?

Comment: What version of Android Studio?

Comment: Android Studio 2.1

Answer (score 9):

Android Studio creates an apk which is signed with a debug certificate when you build your project. This apk is located in the build folder of your project.

A simple way to locate the debug APK is to <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+click (or right click) the "app" directory in the file tree of Android Studio, click "Reveal in Finder" (or "Show in Explorer").

Go to your APK file located in:

app -> build -> outputs -> apk -> debug -> app-debug.apk

That's your .apk file.

Another way you could do it is by going to the Toolbar (at the top) and selecting Build -> Build APK, and let it build. Once it finishes building, you should get a pop-up in the top right corner of Android Studio saying that the APK has been built, with a link below which says "Show in Finder" (or Explorer). Click on it and it will take you to your APK.

Regardless of how you find the APK, just look at the properties of it to get the size.

Answer (score 6):

You can check the generated apk size:

Open *projects* folder

Navigate to your app project folder

Navigate to *App* folder

Navigate to *build* folder

Navigate to *outputs* folder (where apk is located)

Check apk details